# Valid CSS classes?

Tags: css

Are the following valid class names?

```
.text-moretext

.text&text

.text_text

.text(text)
```

I suppose is any CSS class allowed to contain special chracters?

Comment: Dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names

Comment: Put this classes as codes, using the highlight. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `.text-moretext` is allowed
- `.text&text` is not allowed, because the & is a special character in HTML
- `.text_text` is allowed
- `.text(text)` is not allowed

Comment: what about _text-moretext ?

Comment: @YannisDran `.person__hand--left` is fine. This is a style encouraged by BEM syntax http://csswizardry.com/2013/01/mindbemding-getting-your-head-round-bem-syntax/

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use any character in a class name except for whitespace which separates class names: [class is a cdata-list](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-class). Some characters would need escaping. For HTML:

```
<div class="text&amp;moretext"> ... </div>
```

and in a selector:

```
.text\&text { ... }
.text\(text\) { ... }
```

It's generally best to avoid where possible for coding sanity, but yes you can do it if you need to.

Answer (score 5):

According to the CSS Specification, [Section 4.1.3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-identifier):

> In CSS, identifiers  (including
>   element names, classes, and IDs in
>   selectors) can contain only the
>   characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646
>   characters U+00A1 and higher, plus the
>   hyphen (-) and the underscore (_);
>   they cannot start with a digit, or a
>   hyphen followed by a digit.
>   Identifiers can also contain escaped
>   characters and any ISO 10646 character
>   as a numeric code (see next item). For
>   instance, the identifier "B&W?" may be
>   written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F".

So, `.text-moretext` and `.text_text` are valid identifiers (and can be used as class names), while `.text&text` and `.text(text)` are not (although as @bobince pointed out, you can escape the special characters in order to use them as part of an identifier).

Answer (score 1):

Characters A-Z, a-z, digits, hyphen (-) and underscore (_) are the common characters allowed in an class name. (There are some more culture-specific characters allowed, but no other punctuation.)

So, `text-moretext` and `text_text` are valid class names.

When in doubt, be restrictive with punctuation and exotic characters. Some older browsers might not always get it right...